# unable to compile program using -m32 and gcc

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, multiarch

I have installed multi2sim on my 64-bit Ubuntu machine. Both gcc 4.8 and 4.8.1 is installed in my system. Even after setting and exporting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` AND `LD_INCLUDE_PATH`, and installing the `gcc-multilib`, I am facing the following error on compiling with multi2sim:

```
$ sudo gcc -m32 test-argc.c
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc <BR >
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc<BR>
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s<BR>
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s<BR>
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am unable to figure what is wrong. Please help

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 5 years.